# Discord.net issues creating, adding and removing roles

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

so I'm working on a mute and unmute command and what I want it to do is find if there is a role called "Muted" in the server if there is then give the user that role if there isn't then create the role with the necessary permissions. I've tried messing with bot permissions, role permissions, and hierarchy and it just doesn't do anything. There is no error given to me via Console nor is there an error generated in the text, it just simply seems to do nothing no matter what I try, can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I created a pre-existing role called "Muted" and even with the role pre-applied it didn't add it. It also doesn't work while trying to remove the role if I manually added it to the user. This is what I've got:

```
   [Command("mute")]
        [Remarks("Mutes A User")]
        [RequireUserPermission(GuildPermission.MuteMembers)]
        public async Task Mute(SocketGuildUser user)
        {
            var UserCheck = Context.Guild.GetUser(Context.User.Id);

            if (!UserCheck.GuildPermissions.MuteMembers)
            {
                await Context.Message.Channel.SendMessageAsync("", false, new EmbedBuilder()
                {
                    Color = Color.LightOrange,
                    Title = "You dont have Permission!",
                    Description = $"Sorry, {Context.Message.Author.Mention} but you do not have permission to use this command",
                    Author = new EmbedAuthorBuilder()
                    {
                        Name = Context.Message.Author.ToString(),
                        IconUrl = Context.Message.Author.GetAvatarUrl(),
                        Url = Context.Message.GetJumpUrl()
                    }
                }.Build());
            }
            else
            {
                await Context.Guild.GetUser(user.Id).ModifyAsync(x => x.Mute = true);

                var muteRole = await GetMuteRole(user.Guild);
                if (!user.Roles.Any(r => r.Id == muteRole.Id))
                    await user.AddRoleAsync(muteRole);//.ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }



        [Command("unmute")]
        [Remarks("Unmutes A User")]
        [RequireUserPermission(GuildPermission.MuteMembers)]
        public async Task Unmute(SocketGuildUser user)
        {
            var UserCheck = Context.Guild.GetUser(Context.User.Id);

            if (!UserCheck.GuildPermissions.MuteMembers)
            {
                await Context.Message.Channel.SendMessageAsync("", false, new EmbedBuilder()
                {
                    Color = Color.LightOrange,
                    Title = "You dont have Permission!",
                    Description = $"Sorry, {Context.Message.Author.Mention} but you do not have permission to use this command",
                    Author = new EmbedAuthorBuilder()
                    {
                        Name = Context.Message.Author.ToString(),
                        IconUrl = Context.Message.Author.GetAvatarUrl(),
                        Url = Context.Message.GetJumpUrl()
                    }
                }.Build());
            }
            else
            {
                await Context.Guild.GetUser(user.Id).ModifyAsync(x => x.Mute = false).ConfigureAwait(false);

                try { await user.ModifyAsync(x => x.Mute = false);/*.ConfigureAwait(false); */} catch { ReplyAsync("no"); }
                try { await user.RemoveRoleAsync(await GetMuteRole(user.Guild));/*.ConfigureAwait(false); */} catch { ReplyAsync("No lmao"); }
            }
        }

        public async Task<IRole> GetMuteRole(IGuild guild)
        {
            const string defaultMuteRoleName = "Muted";

            var muteRoleName = "Muted";

            var muteRole = guild.Roles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name == muteRoleName);

            if (muteRole == null)
            {
                try
                {
                    muteRole = await guild.CreateRoleAsync(muteRoleName, GuildPermissions.None, Color.Default, false, false);//.ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
                catch
                {
                    muteRole = guild.Roles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name == muteRoleName) ?? await guild.CreateRoleAsync(defaultMuteRoleName, GuildPermissions.None, Color.Default, false, false);//.ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }

            foreach (var toOverwrite in (await guild.GetTextChannelsAsync()))
            {
                try
                {
                    if (!toOverwrite.PermissionOverwrites.Any(x => x.TargetId == muteRole.Id && x.TargetType == PermissionTarget.Role))
                    {
                        await toOverwrite.AddPermissionOverwriteAsync(muteRole, denyOverwrite);//.ConfigureAwait(false);

                        await Task.Delay(200);//.ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
            return muteRole;
        }
```

If anyone can help me that would be great, cheers!

Comment: There's a lot of  things in your code that isn't needed or is redundant. Starting with the use of `RequireUserPermission` precondition and then still checking within the method if the user has the permission. The precondition would prevent the command from running so you'd never get to `If (!UserCheck.GuildPermissions.MuteMember)`. Additionally, your `user` variable is already so `SocketGuildUser` however you do `Context.Guild.GetUser(user.Id)`.

Comment: In `GetMuteRole`, you search for the role, if not found you create it within a `Try` if that fails, you `Catch` and search for the role again? And then attempt to create it once more even though that just failed.

Comment: I would suggest cleaning up your code and then using the [debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019) to step through and see what's actually happening.

Comment: I've used lots of it from another bot so that's why it looks a bit dodgy. But I'll try the debugger thing, thank you.

Comment: If you can pinpoint something weird while debugging that you can't figure out, you can rephrase your question with that additional data.